# Jqgrid alert message when user clicks more than one checkbox

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I was trying to avoid the multiple selection while editing the rows to do that want to check the condition as `if(count>1)` then it shown through an alert message.

I am not getting how to `fetch` the count of selected `checkbox` in **jqGrid**.
successfunc: function (response) {

```
        var msg=response.responseText;

       var n =msg.search("edited");//searching text from edit.php file

       if(n>=0)

        {

       $(".inner").html("
```

X  "+msg+"
");

```
        }

        else

        {

            $(".inner").html("<div class='alert alert-danger fade in'><button class='close' data-dismiss='alert'>X</button><i class='fa-fw fa fa-thumbs-down'></i>  "+msg+" </div>");

            $("#jqgrid").trigger('reloadGrid');

        }
```

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: I think you already have callback functions in jqgrid which you can use.

Answer (score 0):

Try this example

**Html**

```
<input type="checkbox"/>1
<input type="checkbox"/>2
<input type="checkbox"/>3
```

**Script**

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function(){
    var count=0;
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').each(function(index,item){
        if($(item).is(':checked')){
        count++;
        }
    });
    if(count>1)
    {
    alert(count);
    }
});
```

[**Deme**](http://jsfiddle.net/0514am4s/)